# CsvHelper reading blanks as 0 instead of null

Tags: c#, csvhelper

When reading a tab delimited file with CsvHelper it treats blanks as 0 instead of null.  In this case, 0 could be a valid value.  I need to test for null values and let users know something is missing.  Is there a configuration setting I could use to force it to read the blanks as nulls?

Currently doing the following:

```
                var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                config.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                config.Delimiter = "\t";

                config.MissingFieldFound = (HeaderName, index, context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{HeaderName[0]} {index }{ context.Field}");
                };
                config.HeaderValidated = null;
                config.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim ;                                       
                config.RegisterClassMap<NevMap>();

                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config, true))
                {

                    var records = csv.GetRecords<NevValue>().ToList();

                    // check for null values and process file
                    // ...
                 }
```

Comment: What does `NevType` look like? In particular, are the fields you are talking about typed as `int` or as `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: This is almost certainly because you're reading an `int` or `long` value. The default value for those types (`default(int)`) is 0. If you want the fields to be nullable, the type should be `int?` or `long?`.

Comment: Type looks like this:public decimal? 
        public decimal? Foo { get; set; } 
        public DateTime? Bar { get; set; } 
        public int? LegacyId { get; set; }